# $\lim f(x) = L, \lim g(x) = M\implies \lim \max\{f(x),g(x)\} = \max\{L,M\}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

I need to prove the following:

$$\lim_{x\to a} f(x) = L, \lim_{x\to a} g(x) = M\implies \lim_{x\to a} \max\{f(x),g(x)\} = \max\{L,M\}$$

I know I need to, somehow, come up with this: given any $\epsilon>0$, I must show a $\delta>0$ such that

$$|x-a|<\delta\implies |\max\{f(x),g(x)\}-\max\{L,M\}|<\epsilon$$

I tried to use the fact that:

$$f(x)\le\max\{f(x),g(x)\}$$
$$L\le \max\{L,M\}$$
imply $f(x)-L<\max\{f(x),g(x)\}-\max\{L,M\}$ (not always)
and 
$$g(x)\le\max\{f(x),g(x)\}$$
$$M\le \max\{L,M\}$$
imply $g(x)-M<\max\{f(x),g(x)\}-\max\{L,M\}$(not always)

as you can see, it didn't help.

**UPDATE**: using the hints below, I did:

$$\lim \max\{f(x),g(x)\}=\lim\frac{1}{2}[f(x)+g(x)+|f(x)-g(x)|] = \frac{1}{2}[\lim f(x)+\lim g(x)+\lim |f(x)-g(x)|]=$$

$$\frac{1}{2}[L+M+|L-M|] = \max\{L,M\}$$

*by the definition of max given in the hints

Comment: Do you have to give a proof using $\epsilon$ and $\delta$?

Comment: @user84413 no, it was just an idea

Comment: Please do not use titles consisting only of math expressions; these are discouraged for technical reasons -- see [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/8891/title-and-latex).

Comment: Yes, that is correct @GuerlandoOCs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: $\max\{f(x),g(x)\}=\dfrac{1}{2}[f(x)+g(x)+|f(x)-g(x)|]$

Answer (score 2):

First, show that 
$$\lim (f(x)-g(x))=L\mbox{ implies that }\lim |f(x)-g(x)|=|L-M|.$$
Then use this: 
$$\max\{a,b\}=\frac{|a-b|+(a+b)}{2}.$$

Comment: can you take a look at the update in my question?

Answer (score 1):

To avoid using relation between absolute value and max, min function, you have to divide into 3 cases : $L>M, L=M, L<M$. 
We only have to show for first two cases.

1) $L>M$.

Choose $\epsilon =\frac{L-M}{2}>0$, then we can choose $\delta_{1}, \delta_{2}>0$ s.t.

\begin{align}
0<|x-a|<\delta_{1}\Rightarrow|f(x)-L|<\epsilon , 
0<|x-a|<\delta_{2}\Rightarrow |g(x)-M|<\epsilon
\end{align}
Then we can check for $0<|x-a|<\delta=\min\{\delta_{1}, \delta_{2}\}$, $f(x)>g(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to a}\max\{f(x), g(x)\}=\lim_{x\to a} f(x)=M$.

2) $L=M$.

By the same argument, for any $\epsilon>0$ we can choose $\delta>0$ where $0<|x-a|<\delta\Rightarrow L-\epsilon<f(x), g(x)<L+\epsilon\Rightarrow L-\epsilon<\max\{f(x), g(x)\}<L+\epsilon$.